# ubuntu-desktop doesn't work in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

I've installed the Ubuntu Artful (17.10) --- `ubuntu-17.10.1-server-amd64.iso` on my X86 server.

Now I need the desktop environment so I try to install the desktop:

```
apt update && apt install ubuntu-desktop && reboot
```

However, I get an interface as below:
[image]

In fact, it seems to work. I think this is the login interface... Besides, when I get such an interface, I have been able to ssh on the server, which means that the system has booted successfully.

How to fix this issue? I executed the same commands as above to install the desktop for Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the LightDM display manager to replace the default GDM3 can solve this problem:

```
apt install lightdm
```